# Defining custom Firebase key

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I want to store records of students in Firebase for Web as student1, student2, student3, .... In other words, I wish to append a variable i to "student". 
For example, 
key:student1, value:"Mike"
key:student2, value:"Adam"
key:student3, value:"Mike".

So the code I have written for it in Javascript is :

```
                var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
                /* Get worksheet */
                var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
                var i=2,s=1;
                /* Get the value */
                while(true) {
                    //var pid = worksheet['A' + i].v;
                    var student_name = worksheet['B' + i].v;
                    var grp = worksheet['C' + i].v;
                    var proj_title = worksheet['D' + i].v;
                    var teacher=worksheet['E' + i].v;
                    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
                    firebaseRef.child(teacher).set({
                        "grp":grp
                    });
                    firebaseRef.child(teacher).child("grp").set({
                        "proj_title":proj_title,
                        "student" + s.toString: student_name,
                    });
                    i++;
                    s++;
                }
```

But, I am getting error in console as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +
in the line "student" + s.toString: student_name.
Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var data = {
    "proj_title":proj_title
};
data["student" + s.toString] = student_name;
firebaseRef.child(teacher).child("grp").set(data);
```

**"student" + s.toString** is not allowed as the property in the definition of an object.